# How do I link to a specific section on a different HTML page?

Tags: html

I have two HTML pages made for this website, the home page and the about page. In the nav on the home page I have the about page linked with `href="about.html"` which is the name of the file. However the about page also shares `<section id="services">"` which shows the services information. On the nav menu there's a services button that needs to link to this specific section in the about page. How would I do this? I've tried `href="about.html/#services"` but this didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to use `href="about.html#services"` (no slash).